# Should i return the edited model or not

Tags: node.js, rest, backend

If I'm working on a backend server, when the client requests an edit API to a specific product, let's assume that the editing operation done successfully and i updated the row
should I return the updatedProduct or the frontend can do his work

For clarification:
should my response be

```
{ message: "Done" }
```

Or

```
{ message: "Done", product: editedProduct }
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw this being done before on some projects I worked on but please consult your team lead about it and see his/her opinion is.

Comment: I am the one who will do the whole project and thats why i am asking for the best practice way .. 
so what should i return in the response ?

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer.